# May I use Apache NIFI for transfering files to HDFS system.

Tags: apache, file, hdfs, apache-nifi, copying

If yes please guide me basic steps for this. 
I scorll through pages and realized that its possible to do it using core-site.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily transferring files to HDFS File System by using PutHDFS Processor.

Look at this below Link.,

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/

In this processor you have to specify following properties is enough to transfer files into HDFS.

**1.Hadoop Configuration Resources: -A file or comma separated list of files**

```
/Hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/Hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml,/Hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml,/Hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml
```

**2.Directory: Specify location of your HDFS Directory**

```
/FilesFromNiFi/
```

**3.Conflict Strategy:(append/replace/ignore/fail)**

```
append
```

**For example:**

If u need to move the file from local drive into HDFS means using below NiFi workflow

```
GetFile-->PutHDFS

GetFile-->Just give your input directory.

putHDFS-->Specify your HDFS location
```

You need to drag a processor into UI with respect to below image.,

[image]

Refer this link to drag this two processors GetFile and putHDFS into NiFi UI

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#adding-components-to-the-canvas

http://zdatainc.com/2016/02/hello-nifi-data-orchestration-using-hortonworks-dataflow-hdf/

let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: I am unable to locate above components(GetFile PutHDFS) in Apache NiFi?
some settings to include that?

Comment: I have edited my answer.You have to drag those two processor into UI with respect to Link attached in answer

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. My NiFi binary was corrupted and I was seesing only 7 processor as an option to select among.

I am corrected above issue and now its working fine and I am able to see 183 odd processor in the option.